# Split a column of a csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

As a beginner in Python What I'm trying to achieve sounds very easy but I'm unable to get python to work as desired.

I have a csv file with several headers as such:

```
Area    Facility
AAA     car, train, bus
BBB     car
CCC     car, bus, tram
DDD     bicycle
EEE     car, bus, train, tram, walk
FFF     train, tram, plane, helicopter
```

I am trying to split the 'Facility' column into the different words and then run some queries (e.g. unique facilities). My desired output is train, tram, plane, walk etc as a list from column 2.

I am able to successfully split the csv into the two columns but if I further iterate it breaks it down into single letters.

```
import csv

fOpen1=open('C:\data.csv')

Facilities=csv.reader(fOpen1)
unique=[]

for row in Facilities:
    for facility in row[1]:
        if row[13] not in unique:
        unique.append(row[13])
```

I looked around and noticed people using split.lines but had no luck using it either.

Any suggestion/ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for split

> Docstring: S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the delimiter string. 
>   If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If sep is not
>   specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and empty
>   strings are removed from the result.

Basically if you call `split` with no argument, it splits on whitespace (the columns in your dataset), you can split on any other character by calling split with that character, e.g.

```
print("car, train, bus".split(','))
['car', ' train', ' bus']
```

Comment: This works okay but I'm having trouble with the loop now. I guess I will have to figure it out myself. Thank you for your assistance @Maxymoo.

Answer (score 0):

As csv file split columns with `,`, if there is no `,` between the first column and the second column, the output for each line will be like this:

> ['Area    Facility']
>
> ['AAA     car', ' train', ' bus']
>
> ['BBB     car']
>
> ['CCC     car', ' bus', ' tram']
>
> ['DDD     bicycle']
>
> ['EEE     car', ' bus', ' train', ' tram', ' walk']
>
> ['FFF     train', ' tram', ' plane', ' helicopter']

Thus, you can use `split` of the the first element of the `list` to get the first facility. The other facilities is stored in the rest of the `list`. Your target can be achieved as follows:

```
import csv

fOpen1=open('C:\data.csv')

Facilities=csv.reader(fOpen1)
unique=[]

for row in Facilities:
    first_facility = row[0].split()[1] # by default, use space to split
    if first_facility not in unique:
        unique.append(first_facility)
    for rest_facility in row[1:]:
    if rest_facility not in unique:
        unique.append(rest_facility)

print unique
```

Comment: @Hooting- It gives me an error message- List index out of range.

Comment: @VGu please post your input

Comment: My input is similar to the table posted in the original post. Just that there are far more columns. Would you like me to post an extract of this dataset?